# actions-on-google v1->v2 migration: "Error: Response has already been sent"

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm migrating from v1 to the v2 alpha and am getting the following error:

```
Error: Response has already been sent. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the action/intent handler?
at DialogflowConversation.add (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/actionssdk/conversation/conversation.js:51:19)
at DialogflowConversation.close (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/actionssdk/conversation/conversation.js:66:21)
at Request.err [as _callback] (/user_code/index.js:1141:20)
at Request.self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
```

Source:

```
        try {
          conv.close(new SimpleResponse({
            // Sending the details to the user
            speech: textToSpeech1,
            text: displayText1
          }))
        } catch (err) {
            if(err instanceof Error) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.error(new Error(err));
            }
        }
```

Code location: https://github.com/BTS-CM/BeyondBitshares-Firebase/blob/master/index_v2.js#L1141

I don't get why I'm getting the above error, I've not sent a response by this point to the user. Perhaps the request to the external REST API (using requests library) could be counted as a 'Response' perhaps causing this error?

Perhaps it's the format of the simple response within the conv.close() element?

Any idea why this error is occurring?

Cheers

---

Edit:

Think I need to start using async code & promises like this v2 snippet? It appears to responding blank before the REST API query begins..

```
app.intent('tell_greeting', conv => {
  // Return a promise to do async asks, will send everything when promise     resolves
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000))
    .then(() => {
      conv.ask('Hi')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To encourage best practices, the v2 client library requires the use of Promises to perform async requests.

How the response generation works is that it will generate and send the response at the end of the `IntentHandler` function execution unless the function returns a `Promise`, which then it will wait till the `Promise` resolves then send the response.

You can take a look at the [Name Psychic sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/3088cda9d62498b417a1108e09398f754f8e1068/samples/js/app/name-psychic/functions/index.js#L201) contained in the v2.0.0-alpha branch to see a working example:

```es6
app.intent('handle_permission', (conv, params, permissionGranted) => {
  // ...
    return coordinatesToCity(coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude)
      .then(city => {
        conv.user.storage.location = city
        showLocationOnScreen(conv)
      })
  // ...
}
```

`coordinatesToCity` here is a function that returns a `Promise`.

`showLocationOnScreen` here is a function that calls `conv.ask` or `conv.close` and generates the response.

```es6
const showLocationOnScreen = conv => {
  const capability = 'actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT'
  if (conv.surface.capabilities.has(capability) ||
    !conv.available.surfaces.capabilities.has(capability)) {
    return conv.close(...responses.sayLocation(conv.user.storage.location))
  }
  conv.ask(new NewSurface({
    context: responses.newSurfaceContext,
    notification: responses.notificationText,
    capabilities: capability,
  }))
}
```

If your Node.js version supports async await (I think by default starting Node.js 7.6+, but to be safe use Node.js 8+), then you can simplify the code to not chain `.then`:

```es6
app.intent('handle_permission', async (conv, params, permissionGranted) => {
  // ...
    const city = await coordinatesToCity(coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude)
    conv.user.storage.location = city
    return showLocationOnScreen(conv)
  // ...
}
```

Beware that Firebase Functions currently uses Node.js 6 and **currently does not** support async await so you would need a transpiler to use it on there.